# How to retrive user entered password in UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring security 3 may do some trick to validate user's password behind the scene, but that's become my problem right now, I am trying to intercept whatever entered for password by user, and just couldn't find a clue.

```
@Component("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

............

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '"+username+"' not found !");
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

is there any API that I can use to intercept the user's password?

Comment: I don't think `UserDetailsService` is meant to do that. Another component in Spring security is meant to compare the retrieved user credentials with the ones provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserDetailsService` is responsible to load the user and provide a `UserDetails` object that contains the password stored in the database. Unfortunaly (for you) this password is hashed (SHA or MD5) in the most cases.

If you want to intercept the password that is entered by the user, then you have different choices:

- The `UserNamePasswordFilter` (when you use Form Authentication, if you use an other kind of authentication, then you need an other filter) ins one point to intercept the password. It is responsible to fetch the login http request, create a `UserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and forward them to the `AuthenticationManager`.
- An other interception point would be the `AuthenticationManager` (more precise the `ProviderManager` - then only real implemenation of the `AuthenticationManager`). It has a method `Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)` that take the user input (Subclass of `Authentication` for example `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) and verifiy it (by forwarding it to an `AuthenticationProvider`)
- The `AuthenticationProvider` (for example the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`) would be an other place to intercept the password.
- The `DaoAuthenticationProvider` uses a `PasswordEncoder` to hash the user entered password. Then the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` will compare the hash password obtained from the database with the hashed password entered by the user. **So the [`PasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) is probably the easiest way to intercept the user entered password!**
- And of course you can intercept the HttpRequest itself: eighter you register an additional SecurityFilter (before the `UsernamePasswordFilter`) or a simple Servlet Filter (before the Spring Security Filter). (A Spring Interceptor will not work, because the Spring Security Filter will handle the request an will not forward it to the Spring Dispatcher, so the Spring Dispatcher can not invoke the Spring Interceptor.)

password encoder registration:

```
  <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="myPasswordEncoder"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
  </sec:authentication-manager>

 <beans:bean id="myPasswordEncoder"class="InterceptingPassordEncoderSubclassShaPasswordEncoder" />
```